# parse json file to Pydantic model

Tags: python, json, pydantic

I created a model of Pydantic.
But it does not convert and outputs an error
Please tell me,what is wrong.

`classDTO`:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel,Field
from typing import List,Dict
from datetime import date

class OurBaseModel(BaseModel):
    pass
    #class Config:
        #orm_mode = True

class SessionSubjectDTO(OurBaseModel):
    edu_year: int
    semester_type: str
    
class MarkDTO(OurBaseModel):
    semester_number: int
    subject_name: str
    control_type: str
    mark: str  # or int
    session_subject: SessionSubjectDTO #= Field(None, alias="SessionSubjectDTO")
    
class MarksDTO(OurBaseModel):
    __root__: List[MarkDTO]
    
class AttestationDTO(BaseModel):
    subject_name: str
    value: int
    attestation_start_date: date
    
class AttestationsDTO(OurBaseModel):
    __root__: List[AttestationDTO]
    
class DebtDTO(OurBaseModel):
    semester_number: int
    subject_name: str
    control_type: str
    session_subject: SessionSubjectDTO #= Field(None, alias="SessionSubjectDTO")
    
class DebtsDTO(OurBaseModel):
    __root__: List[DebtDTO]
    
class SkipDTO(OurBaseModel):
    valid: int
    no_valid: int
    attestation_start_date: date
    
class SkipsDTO(OurBaseModel):
    __root__: List[SkipDTO]
    
class StudentDTO(OurBaseModel):
    uid: str
    marks: MarksDTO
    attestations: AttestationsDTO
    debts: DebtsDTO
    skips: SkipsDTO
    
class StudentsDTO(OurBaseModel):
    __root__: List[StudentDTO]
```

`example.json`:

```json
[
    {
        "uid": "61c689ac-98a1-11e9-8198-4ccc6a2d123b",
        "marks": [
            {
                "semester_number": 1,
                "subject_name": "454",
                "control_type": "5",
                "mark": "3.",
                "date": "2019-12-27",
                "session_subject": {
                    "id": 4228,
                    "edu_year": 2019,
                    "semester_type": "1"
                }
            }
        ],
        "attestations": [
            {
                "subject_name": "133",
                "value": 2,
                "attestation_start_date": "2019-10-07",
                "attestation_end_date": "2019-10-12"
            }
        ],
        "debts": [
            {
                "semester_number": 4,
                "subject_name": "323",
                "control_type": "12",
                "session_subject": {
                    "id": 22856,
                    "edu_year": 2020,
                    "semester_type": "20"
                }
            }
        ],
        "skips": [
            {
                "valid": null,
                "no_valid": null,
                "attestation_start_date": "2020-03-09",
                "attestation_end_date": "2020-03-14"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

`main.py`:

```py
students = pydantic.parse_file_as(path='192.json', type_=classDTO.StudentsDTO)
```

**Errors:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 73, in <module>
    students  = pydantic.parse_file_as(path='192.json', type_=classDTO.StudentsDTO)
  File "pydantic\tools.py", line 60, in pydantic.tools.parse_file_as
  File "pydantic\tools.py", line 38, in pydantic.tools.parse_obj_as
  File "pydantic\main.py", line 331, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 424 validation errors for ParsingModel[StudentsDTO]
__root__ -> __root__ -> 0 -> attestations -> __root__ -> 18 -> value
  none is not an allowed value (type=type_error.none.not_allowed)
__root__ -> __root__ -> 0 -> attestations -> __root__ -> 19 -> value
  none is not an allowed value (type=type_error.none.not_allowed)
__root__ -> __root__ -> 0 -> attestations -> __root__ -> 20 -> value
  none is not an allowed value (type=type_error.none.not_allowed)
...
__root__ -> __root__ -> 16 -> skips -> __root__ -> 1 -> no_valid
  none is not an allowed value (type=type_error.none.not_allowed)
```

I tried to solve the problem with [Custom Root Types](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#custom-root-types):

> Pydantic models can be defined with a custom root type by declaring the field. `__root__`
>
> The root type can be any type supported by pydantic, and is specified by the type hint on the `__root__` field. The root value can be passed to the model `__init__` via the `__root__` keyword argument, or as the first and only argument to `parse_obj`.

Answer (score 0):

The data in your `example.json` doesn't seem to cause *all* of the errors, only some.

Here's why:

In your `SkipDTO`, for example, you are defining a `no_valid: int` field.

With this definition, that field is *required*, which is why it *cannot* be `null`/`None`.

However, you are passing in:

```json
...
"skips": [
{
        "valid": null,
        "no_valid": null,
        "attestation_start_date": "2020-03-09",
        "attestation_end_date": "2020-03-14"
    }
]
...
```

If `null` is a valid value for `no_valid` (and `valid`) then you need to adapt your model to the following:

```py
from typing import List, Dict, Optional

class SkipDTO(OurBaseModel):
    valid: Optional[int]
    no_valid: Optional[int]
    attestation_start_date: date
```

An `Optional` field will be set to `None` if a `null` value is passed in.

The same is probably the case for `AttestationDTO.value` and maybe other fields in your models.